Magnetic permittivity of core in magnetic circuit with a coil
When describing a coil with a magnetic core in a magnetic circuit with lumped components how the effect of the core is taken into account ?
I think it should be included as a permeance, determined by the core's permeability and its size, in series with the magnetic potential source of the coil but I am not entirely sure.
